# Locating the source a warning from a React project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, debugging, react-proptypes

I have a project that is throwing this warning:

> Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated,
>   and will be removed in  React v16.0. Use the latest available v15.*
>   prop-types package from npm instead. For info on usage, compatibility,
>   migration and more, see https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#prop-types

There are a lot of files importing `PropTypes` like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
```

Also, some files import it like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
```

And ... There are other files importing it like this:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
```

I've gone through and done a find/replace on all 3 of those instances, removing `PropTypes` from that line, and adding a line immediately below it like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

However, the warning is still being thrown in my console.

Can I find the file that is throwing this warning?

Comment: Search with a regex

Comment: It's probably coming from a dependency that hasn't yet upgraded. As @Ted mentioned, search `node_modules` with a regex.